# How to make CSS filter work in VueJS after building?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, vue.js, filter

When developing locally running a Node server, my SVG filter works. However, it doesn't when I build it and run it on a server.

The VueJS project is using Webpack.

I build the app like this:

```
npm run build
```

I have the filter declared like this:

```css
filter: url(#white-glow);
```

When I build the application, the CSS is in a subfolder (/static/css) and I suspect as a result it can't find the filter anymore. When I check the HTML source in my inspector, the SVG filter is there.

When I apply said filter as a style attribute in the HTML it works.

```html
<button style="filter:url(#white-glow);" data-v-32012fc8="">ｍｕｓｉｃ</button>
```

Edit: I cannot use the above method since I want the filter to be active only in the :active state, which you can't do with inline style attribute.

How can I make the filter available in the external CSS file after building the app?

Answer (score 1):

I have added a slash before my url. So now it looks like this in my Vue component and it parses fine when building. It looks like this now in both the component and the built CSS:

```
filter: url('/#white-glow');
```

I have successfully tested this in Firefox 47 and Chrome 70.

Could anybody explain why this works?

Comment: I tried to prefix it with `./` which didn't work.. Havent thought of just the `/` as that usually would be the root path of your domain.

Comment: The preceding slash only works when history mode is off. I haven't figured out how to get it to work whenit's on.

Answer (score 0):

The selector will not work like generic in an external css file.

If you're using the filter only in one file you could theoretically define the rule in the external css file like this:

```
filter: url(http://yourdomain.com/yourwebsite.html#white-glow);
```

Although, this wouldn't really make sense, so I would suggest to place the filter in an external svg file as well and then address it with the full url to the external SVG file in your CSS file

Comment: Thanks! I can confirm this worked when done in my browser's inspector. I haven't tried building it with that path yet however.

Comment: I found a fix similar to the one given by you. I tried including the SVG in the HTML which worked for the root path with my preceding slash 'fix'. Having the SVG as separate asset worked, once I figured out how to address it with relative paths. CSS-loader converts it to a base64 string so it's neatly contained in the CSS itself after building it.